# How can I make a page act like its own website on a web server?

Tags: html, forwarding

Here's an example:
Domain1.com goes to a webpage
However, Domain2.com points to another webpage in a FOLDER in the same web server.
But when you go to Domain2.com/nonexsistentfile.html, it gives you the 404 error page of Domain1.com.
I'm using GoDaddy to host what Domain2.com represents but I need it to mask Domain1.com/folder/anotherfolder/domain2'sindexpage.html and also handle links in the same URL
This probably made no sense but if you could help it would be appreciated :)
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm correct, you should be able to point your domain to a folder using the Control Panel from GoDaddy.

If you then point your domain to the main folder and place more folders in that main folder, every folder in that main folder will be part of the domain.

So for example,

```
Domain1.com: ROOT/MAINFolder1/folder2/folder3/etc.
Domain2.com: ROOT/MAINFolder2/folder2/folder3/etc.
```

This will make it so that you have 2 domains pointing to 2 different folders on the same web server.

Comment: Could you tell me where this is in the control panel? This would be very useful

Comment: I'm not 100% where to find it on the control panel of GoDaddy as most web hosts use different panels. It should be called something like 'Domain Pointer'.